# LogicalTree Control directly under mouse no VisualTree

Tags: wpf, mouse, mousedown, visualtreehelper, frameworkelement

This is a WPF application.

I'm trying to get the control directly under the mouse and it's proving to be a surprising pain.

Mouse.DirectlyOver, InputHitTest and VisualTreeHelper.HitTest all reference the VISUAL tree.  I'm trying to grab the control itself.

Example: If I have a TextBox and use any of the above, it will return a TextBoxView whereas I want the TextBox itself.

This is happening inside of a PreviewLeftButtonDown event.  Sender is not an option as Sender is always a ListViewItem for me.  If I check e.OriginalSource it is still the VisualTree element and not the actual control.

Happy to explain further if need be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with mdm20 that the only way to get to the `Textbox` is by traversing up to the parent. In fact, [here is a link to the same question asked a couple of years ago](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/wpf/thread/efefef84-8139-4726-b174-44bdbe9326d1), with the same answer. If you want to limit unnecessary tree traversal, then you could stop searching once you hit the `ListViewItem`, as anything above that point is not what you are looking for anyway.

However, add the last link and [this one together](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/1ea114ff-1bb7-48c6-9cd6-04f1d1aa92a7), and it actually seems to me that you already have your answer. If a `TextBoxView` is returned, then you know that a textbox was hit. You could even cache the incoming `TextBox` that goes through the `HitTestFilterCallBack` potentially, but that is more of a theory and possibly bug prone. However, going down that path, you could just test if the `TextBox` coming through the filter is the parent of the `TextBoxView`

Comment: This will be accepted answer.

TextBoxView is what I ended up using.  The TextBoxView is what actually contains the text anyways which is what I was really after.  I wanted to AVOID triggering a drag if the user was dragging within a textBox to select some text.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You just need to walk up the visual tree until you find the type you want.  Here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/75816/Walk-up-the-Visual-Tree) to some code.

Here's the code from that link

```
// walk up the visual tree to find object of type T, starting from initial object
public static T FindUpVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject initial) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject current = initial;

    while (current != null && current.GetType() != typeof(T))
    {
         current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    return current as T;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This would work but I don't like walking the tree as this is going to happen often.

Also I'd be concerned about inadvertently hitting the wrong TextBox (what if a control is templated and there are mutliple textboxes leading up to the parent.(=)

In the end JustinPihony's answer fulfills my need.

Answer (score 1):

Walk up the visual tree until you find a `UIElement`:

```
public UIElement FindUIElement(DependencyObject visualTreeNode)
{
    UIElement elem;
    while ((elem = (visualTreeNode as UIElement)) != null)
        visualTreeNode = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visualTreeNode);
    return elem;
}
```